# Capturing android touch drawing coordinates as paths

Tags: android, touch-event

Using an example found here:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTouch/article.html I'm able to draw a path every time a finger touches the screen and that works great, Is there any way that I can capture that drawn path and reproduce it in another view in other coordinates? Like capturing the full drawn image and reproducing it scaled in a segment of the other view?

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save your drawn image and save it as a bitmap. Then you can scale it with Matrix or Canvas and redraw it by calling to where you want to draw